# Sqlite3.OperationalError near "."

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

I am writing a python script to import a csv file into a pre-made sqlite database. The table is already created, but I am having trouble with the following two lines of code:

```
c.execute('.mode csv')
c.execute('.import %s tempData', fileName)
```

I am getting the error message as stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DB-API interface is for SQL. Those are commands meant to be used with the SQLite CLI tool and as such cannot be used with DB-API. You will need to either perform the equivalent operations in your code or invoke the CLI tool instead.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to find the DB-API and use the appropriate csv operations.